# Marshal.SizeOf(Type t) function

Tags: c#, .net

I understand that `SizeOf()` is supposed to be used to interact with unmanaged code, but my question is why does `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(System.Char))` return `1` instead of `2`? I would assume that `C# char` is supposed to be equivalent to unmanaged `wchar_t` which is 2 bytes in size. Would that cause problems?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [Marshal.SizeOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/5s4920fa%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> For character types, the size is affected by the `CharSet` value applied to that class.

And according to [CharSet Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.runtime.interopservices.charset%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), the default is `CharSet.Ansi`:

> Although the common language runtime default is `Auto`, languages may override this default. For example, by default C# marks all methods and types as `Ansi`.

---

For example:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct A
{
    char c;
}
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
struct B
{
    char c;
}

....

Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(A)), Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(B)));
```

the output is

```
1 2
```

Comment: Can you edit and add the code that changes the CharSet and makes SizeOf() return 2?

Comment: Funny, I was just re-reading Joel Spolsky's post on character sets today. Good catch. http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: But this doesn't explain why does `Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(char))` return 1. What does C# do with types created in it shouldn't have anything to do with that.

Comment: @svick I guess if we could somehow add `StructLayout ... CharSet.Unicode` to the native type `char` (as we do for custom types), then `Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(char))` would be 2.

Comment: @AlexD But the quote says that default is `Auto`, which is the same as `Unicode` on any modern system. And since C# didn't force it to `Ansi` (like for your `A`), I don't understand why it returns 1.

Comment: @svick Let's say `struct A` has no `StructLayout` attribute at all. Still, `Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(A))==1`. So the default, in case of C#, is `Ansi` (as the end of the quote says). And `char` (or `System`s `struct Char`) should give the same result. But I think see your point. The documentation could be more explicit. That _"marks all methods and types as Ansi"_ is a bit fuzzy.